# Django's HttpResponseRedirect() + reverse() truncating port number in URL

Tags: django, django-urls

I run my local development server on port 8000 because my ISP blocks port 80. The problem is when using:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foobar'))
```

Django (for some reason) truncates the port from the URL - but it has no problem resolving it in the context of template tags e.g.: {% url foobar %}.

Since I'm attempting to reduce the number of manual changes required to deploy to our production server, I'd like to avoid hardcoding the url.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse()` and `{% url %}` don't take any account of the domain and port - they just operate on the path. So the result of `reverse('foobar')` is the element in your urls.py that matches to 'foobar' - for example, `/foo/bar/`.

So something else must be changing your URL - perhaps your browser.

Answer (score 0):

What does reverse('foobar') evaluate to at that point?

Is the correct host:port of the site entered in the sites table (Admin page is usually http://localhost:8000/admin/sites/site/ if admin is enabled)

Can you use curl -i  to get the complete response from the server?

Comment: Ah - yeah that's probably worth mentioning - it resolves to http://staging.devdomain.com/foobar/ so it's resolving correctly - except it should be http://staging.devdomain.com:8000/foobar/

Comment: Oh and I'm not using the Django Admin - so it is set to the default of example.com